# Click on element simultaneously in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I created a very simple layout where users can tap on a div simultaneously:

```
<div class="wrap">
      <div class="tap-zone top" @click="scoreTop += 1">{{ scoreTop }}</div>
      <div class="middle">{{ score() }}<div>{{ won }}</div><div @click="reset()">reset</div></div>
      <div class="tap-zone bottom" @click="scoreBottom += 1">{{ scoreBottom }}</div>
</div>
```

while tapping on it, a score counts up.
The issue is that on mobile browsers, clicking (tapping) does not work simultaneously so when two people hammer on the divs, the scores won't count up. Only if you hit one div at a time, it would work.

What event would be suitable for this and is it even possible with native behaviour?
I browsed various extensions for this but none seems to work as expected.

Comment: why don't you define a method for that, so based on the arg passed you can add 1 to the corresponding variable

Comment: that is not the problem - the problem is that its not possible to hit two click events simultaneously e.g. on `tap-zone top` and `tap-zone bottom` the same time.

Comment: search about touch event libraries for vue. that may help

Comment: solved it without a library: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events